# Non ordinal INT as Enum

Tags: java, enums

Please consider the following java enum:

```
public enum carrier {
    Default(0),
    CarrierOne(1),
    CarrierTwo(2),
    CarrierWhoKnows(102312);
    private final int value;
    private static final Map<Integer, carrier> carrierMap = new HashMap<Integer, carrier>();

    static {
        for (carrier type : carrier.values()) {
            carrierMap.put(type.value, type);
        }
    }

    private carrier(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static int getIntValue(int value) {
        return value;
    }

    public static carrier getStringValue(int value) {
        return carrierMap.get(value);
    }
}
```

What I need is for getIntValue to return the value as it does
(ie, 102312) however, as an enum and not an int. Is it possible
to cast the int value 102312 as an enum.
Please note, I am not referring to the ordinal (we don't use that),
or the string value which is correctly returned in `getStringValue`.
I am referring to returning the value 102312 as an enum instead of int.

Thanks in Advance,

Nick.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Why would you want this?

Comment: From what I can tell getStringValue does exactly what you're saying you want getIntValue to do. Please clarify. In any case, Enums are neither Strings nor ints; you cannot cast from int to any class (other than autoboxing to Integer) because int is not a class.

Comment: Why do you return the passed in `value` in `getIntValue(int value)`? What on earth is it supposed to do? Finally, `getStringValue` does not return a `String`.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You already *have* the enum if you're trying to call a method.

Comment: Consider following the usualy Java naming convention, class names start with upper case: `public enum Carrier`. Makes it much easier for others to read your code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you just want to get enum member by it int value.

```
public static carrier getStringValue(int value) {
    for(carrier c : carrier .values()){
        if(c.value == value) return c;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Got illegal value");
}
```

Please check you code to be more readable. Change method names, rename enum name(must be Carrier), think about `getIntValue` method signature and implemetnation. Looks like it should be opposite to `getStringValue` and return int value of enum member

```
public static int getIntValue(carrier c) {
   if(c == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Got null, expected carrier");     
   return c.value;
}
```

Comment: To be more understandable `getStringValue` should be named like `getByValue`